# Why is the sep='.' not working in this code?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the full name input by the user into its initials and then print the initials to the screen. We must use loops and lists.

I've searched online and can not find an answer specific to what I am trying to do.

```py
fullName = input('Please enter your full name: ')

name = []

for i in fullName:
    if i.isupper():
        name.append(i)

for i in name:
    print(i, sep='.', end='')
```

I want the printout to be `A.B.C`.  I am currently getting `ABC`.

What am I doing wrong or not seeing?

Comment: You need to pass comma-separated values in the print function. Right now, you are passing only one value at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In This code,

```
for i in name: 
    print(i ,sep='.',end='')
```

print gets each single element `i` in `name` in every loop iteration, so it's one object at a time. You need to pass objects to print func. You can do something like this by unpacking your `name` list and passing it to print

```
print(*name ,sep='.',end='')
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's reduce the code to a minimal example. The input and preprocessing steps are irrelevant:

```
name = list('ABC')
for i in name:
    print(i, sep='.', end='')
```

This is equivalent to calling

```
print ('A', sep='.', end='')
print ('B', sep='.', end='')
print ('C', sep='.', end='')
```

Hopefully you can see that each print statement is printing exactly one thing, meaning that `sep` never comes into play. You would want to split the elements of your list (or string) into separate arguments to a *single* call to `print`.

The simplest way is to use star expansion:

```
print(*name, sep='.')
```

Alternatively, you can do the formatting yourself:

```
print('.'.join(name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `print(i, sep='.', end='')` with `print(i, sep='', end='.')`

Or you can print a formatted string like

```
name = '.'.join(name)
print(name)
```

Comment: I didn't get the extra trailing dot thing. 
name = ['A', 'B']
print(".".join(name)) is printing A.B

Comment: @Bhawan You get a trailing dot using the first solution (`end='.'`).

Answer (score 0):

You need a different approach, because people often do not capitalize their names:

```
fullName = input('Please enter your full name: ')

# convert first characters of every word to upper case
initials = [i[0].upper() for i in fullName.split()]

# print them out, joining by a dot '.'
print( '.'.join(initials) )
```

Answer (score 0):

In `print()` `sep=` specifies how to seperate obejcts input to print statement not characters in string.

```
In[1]: print('A', 'B', sep='.')
```

prints:

```
A.B
```

but this:

```
In[2]: print('AB', sep='.')
```

prints:

```
AB
```

because 'AB' is one string object and there is nothing to separate, while 'A','B' are two string objects.
For reference:[print()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#print)